# Custom Seekbar in android

Tags: java, android, android-seekbar

I am trying to build the custom seekbar in Android.What I have done is like

[Custom SeekBar](http://postimg.org/image/oc09ta8f9)

I want is to show the progress below the seekbar like

[Desired Image](http://s1.postimg.org/d3divi8rj/14283245376243.png)

Here is my code

```
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    try {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        mText = String.valueOf(getProgress());
        mTextWidth = mPaint.measureText(mText);
        Rect bounds = this.getProgressDrawable().getBounds();

        float xImg = bounds.width() * getProgress() / getMax() + imagepaddingleft + oldPaddingLeft;
        float yImg = imagepaddingtop + oldPaddingTop;
        float xText = bounds.width() * getProgress() / getMax() + mImgWidth / 2 - mTextWidth / 2 + textpaddingleft + oldPaddingLeft;
        float yText = yImg + textpaddingtop + mImgHei / 2 + getTextHei() / 4;

        canvas.drawBitmap(bm, xImg, yImg, mPaint);
        canvas.drawText(mText, xText, yText, mPaint);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you be more specific? @Soham

Comment: @Soham
you need to implement  the seekbar change listener callback in your activity or fragment where you are creating your seekbar instance.

yourseekbarinstance.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        //Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        //Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        //Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
}

});

Place your remaining logic in these methods.

Comment: @DanialHussain . Why should I override the changelister()  method. I am already getting correct value. What my need is the bitmap that I am drawing is need to be down the line of the seekbar.Now it is showing above the seekbar.

Comment: Then just correct the Y axis value of that image.

Comment: @FahidNadeem.Check my edited answer.Is it enough?

Comment: @Stan.I was trying to do that,but not working.Can you tell me what can be the value.Thanks

Comment: @Soham you are doing wrong you are adding it to canvas of seek bar that's why it's not taking the desired location in y-axis.

Comment: Ok,So what's your solution?Can you provide some code and explain me in details.It will be better.Thanks @DanialHussain

Answer (score 0):

Please download samples from below link and modify according to your need

1. https://github.com/dolphinwang/RangeSeekbar
2. https://github.com/karabaralex/android-comboseekbar
3. https://github.com/vashisthg/StartPointSeekBar

if you want some other custom seek bar then you can goto below link:
https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar

i hope it will help.